# GNU Octave (Matlab) COVID-19 SIR-X Model

Tags: octave, ode, data-fitting

I'm trying to do the same as descriped in this article: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/early/2020/04/07/science.abb4557.full.pdf

I use GNU Octave.

This is the function file with the ODE System:

```
function f = COVID19ODE(t,y0)

  alpha = 3.07*0.38;
  beta = 0.38;
  kappa = 0.5;
  kappa0 = 0.5;
  ydot =@(t,y,a) ([-alpha*y(1)*y(2) - kappa*y(1);
                  alpha*y(1)*y(2) - beta*y(2) - kappa0*y(2) - kappa*y(2);
                  (kappa0 + kappa)*y(2);
                  kappa0*y(1) + beta*y(2)]);
  odeopt = odeset ("InitialStep", 1e-2, "MaxStep", 1);           
  [t,y] = ode45(ydot, t, y0, odeopt);
  f = y;
endfunction
```

This is the script to fit the data to the ODE model:

```
pkg load optim

Cases = [2,3,20,79,150,227,320,445,650,888,1128,1694,2036,2502,3089,3858,4636,5883,7375,9172,10149,12462,15113,17660,21157,24747,27980,31506,35713,41035,47021,53578,59138,63927,69176,74386,80539,86498,92472,97689,101739,105792,110574,115242,119827,124632,128948,132547,135586,139422,143626,147577,152271];
Days = (1:1:length(Cases));

% Fit
xdata = Days;
ydata = Cases';
F = @(a,xdata) COVID19ODE(xdata,a)(:,3);
a0=[1 1 1 1];
[a,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(F,a0,xdata,ydata);

% Plot
plot(Days,Cases,'-+' , Days,F(a,Days)) 
grid
legend("Cases" , "Fit" , "location","northwest")
title('Covid 19 pandemic')
xlabel('Days')
ylabel('Cases')
```

The computation takes very long and in the end there is an error message:

```
warning:  Solving was not successful.  The iterative integration loop exited at time t = 1.000000 before the endpoint at tend= 53.000000 was reached.  This may happen if the stepsize becomes too small.  Try to reduce the value of 'InitialStep' and/or'MaxStep' with the command 'odeset'.
warning: called from
    integrate_adaptive at line 312 column 7
    ode45 at line 232 column 12
    COVID19ODE at line 12 column 8
    COVID19Model>@<anonymous> at line 9 column 16
    nonlin_curvefit>@<anonymous> at line 84 column 14
    __nonlin_residmin__>@<anonymous> at line 316 column 41
    __lm_svd__ at line 469 column 11
    __nonlin_residmin__ at line 452 column 21
    nonlin_curvefit at line 83 column 18
    lsqcurvefit at line 268 column 19
    COVID19Model at line 11 column 30
```

I tried to reduce the value of 'InitialStep' and/or 'MaxStep' but it didn't help. 
The fit-function doesn't seem to be a good approximation for the data:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7HJd.png)

Comment: Could you please add more on how you built the model, the paper is rather sparse on implementation details. The paper uses population densities, your code uses counts. At least the `alpha` parameter has to be adapted to it. From the SIXR components you compare the given case numbers to the X component of isolated, "removed" persons. Is that really also the definition of the data you compare against, or would it be more realistic to add a fraction of `I`? For a total population of millions or tens of millions your initial point is rather far away.

Comment: I followed what these guys did: http://rocs.hu-berlin.de/corona/docs/forecast/model/
It should work but unfortunately I'm not able to get the same results.

The difference between densities and counts is a constant factor so I guess it shouldn't be a general error.

You are right, my initial guess is not that good. I changed it to
a0=[1e7 1e4 1e3 1e2];
The result is an endless computation time.

Comment: Well, the model is faulty as it does not take the ramp-up in the number of tests into account, and the changing of reporting guidelines. If a test is only or mainly performed if a transmission possibility can be established, you can also get a similar exponential initial "infection" pattern from an unspecific test for some human genetic marker (like blue eyes) unrelated to any virus. The "super-spreader" stories for instance could be a self-fulfilling prophesy, testing a large number of people will lead to a percentage of positive test results. Let's not start with the fraud that RT-PCR is.

Comment: If you change from density to sizes, you need to divide `alpha` by the total population size. Or you do as the paper does, use densities and for the optimization introduce a scaling factor as additional parameter and multiply the density result with this scale factor before returning to the fitting function.

Comment: Ok, my new fit-section looks is:
`% Fit
xdata = Days;
ydata = Cases';
F = @(a,xdata) 5e7*COVID19ODE(xdata,a)(:,3);
a0=[1e6 1e4 1e3 1e2];
[a,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(F,a0,xdata,ydata);`
and I removed the `odeopt = odeset ("InitialStep", 1e-3, "MaxStep", 1e-1);`
from the function file. Still leading to endless computation.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the paper, we have the "best" coefficients of the model for the case of densities that add up to one, `S+I+X+R=1`, which amounts to 3 free parameters for the initial value. With the assumption `X=R=0` in the IC, one parameter remains, so that the initial conditions could be parametrized as `S0 = 0.9+0.1/(1+x^2)` and `I=1-S0`. Further it is assumed that the case number is proportional to the `X` component, which would give a second parameter for the proportionality factor.

Make the kappas variable in a range from 0 to 0.2 via `kappa = 0.2/(1+5*exp(u))`. Even then the use of `kappa0` is rejected, with the parameters

```
prop =  49040365.30572
y0 =

   1.0000e+00   1.1947e-06   1.0000e-16   1.0000e-16

kappa =  0.042094
kappa0 = 0
```

I get the logarithmic plot 
[image]

In many other variations of the parametrization, the solver does not find any sensible solution, usually if a solution is found at all, the `S` component falls too fast.

The code for this image is

```matlab
  % data and other initializations left out
  C = @(Y) Y(:,3);
  L = @(Y) log(1+Y);
  F = @(a,xdata) L(C(COVID19ODE(xdata,a)));

  a0=[0.1 log(1e9) 0 0 ];
  [a,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(F,a0,xdata,L(ydata));
  disp("a="); disp(a);
  % Plot
  time=Days(1):0.1:Days(end);
  semilogy(Days,Cases,'+r' , time,COVID19ODE(time,a)); 
  grid
  legend("Cases" , "S","I","X","R" ); % , "location","northwest")
  title('Covid 19 pandemic')
  xlabel('Days')
  ylabel('Cases')

  function f = COVID19ODE(t,para)
    ic = para(1);
    prop = exp(para(2))
    S0 =  0.9+0.1/(1+ic^2); 
    y0 = [ S0-2e-16, 1-S0, 1e-16, 1e-16 ]
    beta = 0.38;
    alpha = 3.07*beta;
    kappa = 0.2/(1+5*exp(para(3)))
    kappa0 = 0.2/(1+5*exp(para(4)))
    ydot =@(t,y,a) ([-alpha*y(1)*y(2) - kappa*y(1);
                    alpha*y(1)*y(2) - beta*y(2) - kappa0*y(2) - kappa*y(2);
                    (kappa0 + kappa)*y(2);
                    kappa0*y(1) + beta*y(2)]);
    odeopt = odeset ("InitialStep", 1e-2, "MaxStep", 0.1, "AbsTol", 1e6);           
    [t,y] = ode45(ydot, t, y0, odeopt);
    f = prop*y;
  end%function
```